# How to show an Image as a Tool Tip using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, image, tooltip

I have a requirement something like "Showing the tool tip as an image."
I want to show the image in the tool tip. Is it possible to show this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try any of the following plugins with jquery

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: Is it not possible with plain Jquery or Javascript ?

Comment: @Multiplexer: Every plugin is plain jQuery just presented in an easy way to implement it in different websites. You can start writing jQuery/JS from scratch, then test it in all browsers, fix bugs, performance, etc.. you need to know how to do it and you need the time for it. Or you can just use an already built and tested plugin. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything is possible. Of course there is no 'native' way of doing it, you can't just add an image to the 'title' attribute.

You need to use JavaScript.

You can either write your own code or use some kind of plugin.

I recommend using some of the great jQuery plugins available out there. Just google it and choose the one that best fits your needs.

here is a start:
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

And a very simple tutorial: http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery

Hope it helps.